# MongoDB - get list of embedded items

Tags: php, mongodb

I have have a collection called `users`. Each user document has an embedded document called phone numbers.

```
}
   "_id": ObjectId("4f2984b1af06e80418000000"),
   "User_FirstName": "Frank",
   "User_LastName": "Williams",
   "User_PhoneNumbers": [
                  {"Phone_Type": "Home","Phone_Number: "555-555-5555" },
                  {"Phone_Type": "Mobile","Phone_Number: "333-333-3333" }
                  ]
}
```

I am trying to display all the phone numbers for the user named "Frank Williams".  I would like to use a loop that returns the results (all phone numbers for a particular user):

```
Home, 555-555-5555
Mobile, 333-333-33333
```

I am new to mongodb and don't know how to query an embedded document and have it return all the embedded documents for that particular user.  I am coding in php.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At best you can return only the whole `User_PhoneNumbers` array. You cannot pick individual items out of it. (I am talking about regular queries, of course. With map-reduce or upcoming Aggregation Framework you'll be able to do this).

```
db.collection.find({"_id": ObjectId("4f2984b1af06e80418000000")}, 
                   {"User_PhoneNumbers": 1, _id: -1});
```

This query will return this document:

```
{
   "User_PhoneNumbers": [
              {"Phone_Type": "Home","Phone_Number": "555-555-5555" },
              {"Phone_Type": "Mobile","Phone_Number": "333-333-3333" }
            ]
}
```

Then in PHP you can handle it however you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Ok so I get that is how you run the query in the shell but do you know who it is run in php? $cursor = $collection->find(array("_id"=> ObjectId("4f2984b1af06e80418000000"),array("User_PhoneNumbers"))?  I tried this but not working.  Thank.

Comment: @user982853: I believe, it's `$collection->find(array("_id"=> ObjectId("4f2984b1af06e80418000000"),array("User_PhoneNumbers" => 1))`

Comment: I hate to bother you with this but when i try a loop it doesn't return anything.  Am i doing something wrong: $cursor= $collection->find(array("_id"=> ObjectId("4f2984b1af06e80418000000"),array("User_PhoneNumbers" => 1)); foreach ($cursor as $key){echo $key['Phone_Number'];}?> and this throws the error: Undefined index: User_PhoneNumbers in C:\wamp...

Comment: Probably, I don't know. You should learn how to debug your code.